# Barra de progreso en Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Buenas noches estoy desarrollando una app en Django 1.10, usando el framework Bootstrap. En mi app tengo una vista donde se generan unos informes, los cuales suelen demorarse algunos segundos por la cantidad de registros que manejo en la base de datos, lo que quisiera implementar es que al momento que se este generando el informe, al usuario se le muestre una barra de progreso o algo que indique que esta cargando.

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Buenas, Te aconsejo la librería *pace.js*. Búscala en GitHub.

Comment: Puedes agregar código?  probablemente necesites hacerlo en JS (lo digo porque solo tienes la etiqueta de Django)

Comment: Mira hasta él momento no he encontrado cómo hacerlo en tiempo real es decir que mandes al front cuantos registros son y posteriormente estarle mandando el contador de los registros procesados. Lo que he echo es la ajax vía jquery solicita el procedimiento a través de una url y con ajax manejas eventos como sucess done etc ya con estos eventos puedes ocultar un div o bien ocultarlo o imprimir en un label o spas un texto